# Is there an exception, that lets me handle the occasion when the user tries to input too much character for a UUID?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, controller

I am writing a small program for university. My task is to write a java spring rest application that can do **CRUD** operations. I dont have to make forms that displays the results of the queries, its okay if I test it with postman or rested.

Im making a book store, and of course every book has a unique **UUID**. Here is my controller file.

```
package controllers;

import bookstore.exceptions.DateIsToLateException;
import bookstore.exceptions.NoMatchingIDException;
import bookstore.models.Book;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import services.BookService;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.UUID;

import static java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType.A;

@RestController
public class BookController {
    private BookService service;

    public BookController(@Autowired BookService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/count", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String showNumberOfBooks(){
        return String.valueOf(service.getBooks().size());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<Book> getAllBook(){
        return service.getBooks();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Book addNewBook(@RequestBody Book book) throws DateIsToLateException, NoMatchingIDException {
        service.addBook(book);
        return service.getBook(book.getId());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/title/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<Book> getBookbyTitle(@PathVariable String title){
        Collection<Book> books= service.getBook();
        Collection<Book> result = new ArrayList<Book>();

        for (Book b: books){
            if(b.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
                result.add(b);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/genre/{genre}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<Book> getBookByGenre(@PathVariable String genre){
        Collection<Book> books= service.getBooks();
        Collection<Book> result = new ArrayList<Book>();

        for (Book b: books){
            if(b.getGenre().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(genre)){
                result.add(b);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Book getBookById(@PathVariable UUID id) throws NoMatchingIDException {
        return service.getBook(id);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoMatchingIDException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleNoMatchingIDException(Exception e){
        return "Corresponding UUID does not exist. Maybe a typo? " + e.getMessage();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(DateIsToLateException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleDateIsToLateException(Exception e){
        return "Date is invalid! Maybe the date you've entered is after 1 years of today's date? " + e.getMessage();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String deleteBook(@PathVariable UUID id) throws NoMatchingIDException {
        service.deleteBook(id);
        return "Deleting succesful";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/books/year/{year}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Collection<Book> getBooksFromYear(@PathVariable int year){
        Collection<Book> books = service.getBooks();
        Collection<Book> thisYearBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Book b: books){
            if(b.getYearofPublication().getYear() == year){
                thisYearBooks.add(b);
            }
        }
        return thisYearBooks;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public Book updateBook(@PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody Book book) throws DateIsToLateException, NoMatchingIDException {
        book.setId(id);
        service.updateBook(book, id);
        return book;
    }

}
```

For example, you can make the GET request for a book by id like:
http:localhost:8080/books/{here goes a long UUID}

My problem is that i can handle if I put in a wrong, not existing UUID, but if I try to append plus 4-5 characters to the end of the UUID, I dont get any Exceptions, but the program still crashes. If this happens, I would like to make a text like "Too many characters for an UUID" or something like that. Is there a way I can handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Book getBookById(@PathVariable("id") @NotBlank @Size(max = 10, message="Too many characters for an UUID") UUID id) throws NoMatchingIDException {
    return service.getBook(id);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, im gonna check it tonight, and mark it as an answer, if it is the solution.